# ReasonML way of returning various types from a single switch statement

Tags: pattern-matching, reason, bucklescript

I have predefined types that goes,

```
type objA = {name: string}
type objB = {age: int}
```

and I want to have a variant type that goes,

```
type test = 
| Atype(objA)
| Btype(objB)
```

and ultimately use pattern-matching to properly return the values of what each type is encompassing.

```
let testVariant = {name: "helloworld"}
switch(testVariant: test){
| Atype(v) => v
| Btype(v) => v
}
```

But since the variant values inside Atype and Btype are different, this is not possible. My question is, how do I return some data with different types conditionally using pattern matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using GADT (To get a better understand read this [Sketch](https://sketch.sh/s/yH0MJiujNSiofDWOU85loX/)).

```
type objA = {name: string};
type objB = {age: int};

type test('a) =
  | Atype(objA): test(string)
  | Btype(objB): test(int);

let testVariant: type a. test(a) => a = {
  fun 
  | Atype(v) => v.name
  | Btype(v) => v.age
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this plus the '@unboxed solved my issue! '@unboxed pulls out the value wrapped by variant. For anybody interested, check it out from https://rescript-lang.org/blog/bucklescript-release-7-0-2.

Comment: can you repost the link Sketch?

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with Sketch. I had forked this sketch but unable to view the list of my sketches in my profile due to some error. Will wait for the sketch team to fix it and will repost the link once everything is up and running

Comment: Hey it seems the issue with sketch.sh is still not resolved. Till the issue is fixed, you can use the following PDF of the sketch. [PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9noljfk9y9bh7w/GADTs_%20A%20primer%20-%20Sketch.sh.pdf?dl=0)